# How can I convert the mongo queries which are in js format to liquibase script using runCommand?

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

I am new to mongodb here's an example what we are trying to do-

The js format-------->

```
print('Apiheaders migration - add environmentId field');
db.apiheaders.find().forEach(
    function(apiHeader) {
        if (!apiHeader.environmentId) {
            let existingApiHeaderCursor = db.apiheaders.find({'_id': apiHeader._id, environmentId: 'DEFAULT'});
            if(!existingApiHeaderCursor.hasNext()) {
                apiHeader.environmentId = 'DEFAULT';
                db.apiheaders.save(apiHeader);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

and converted it to--------->

```
<ext:runCommand>
      <ext:command>
        {
          update: "apiheaders",
          updates: [
            {
              q: {}, u: { $set: { environmentId: "DEFAULT" } }, multi: true
            }
          ]
        }
      </ext:command>
</ext:runCommand>
```

I want to convert many more queries like this and I am stuck on this one---------->

```
print('In apis collection, scopes of json-validation policy have to be changed from REQUEST/RESPONSE to REQUEST_CONTENT/RESPONSE_CONTENT');
db.apis.find({ definition: /"json-validation" : {"scope":"REQUEST"|"json-validation" : {"scope":"RESPONSE"/}).forEach(api => {
    api.definition = api.definition
        .replace(/"json-validation" : {"scope":"REQUEST"/, "\"json-validation\" : {\"scope\":\"REQUEST_CONTENT\"")
        .replace(/"json-validation" : {"scope":"RESPONSE"/, "\"json-validation\" : {\"scope\":\"RESPONSE_CONTENT\"");
    db.apis.save(api);
});
```

If anyone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered converting the json to sql:
https://blog.sqlizer.io/posts/mongodb-sqlizer-api/

Then run the changesets in liquibase in [native sql](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html)